# iOS Core Data can't open image from stored URI

Tags: ios, core-data

In my app i store images in my documents folder and store their URI in the database.

Whenever i'm trying to load the image based on the URI stored in the db, i get "nil" back as a result.

The stored URI looks like this:

> /Users/myname/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/6.0/Applications/78325CF9-73B0-4D0D-B136-FD8FF8D837C1/Documents/WC_45FEAF25-AC0C-4E91-A5E2-AA48215F1E48-3147-000005C6C9E65B42.jpg

When i look into it from iTerm i see that the image is there, but in iTerm i have to cd into the directory like this:

> /Users/myname/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\
>   Simulator/6.0/Applications/78325CF9-73B0-4D0D-B136-FD8FF8D837C1/Documents/WC_45FEAF25-AC0C-4E91-A5E2-AA48215F1E48-3147-000005C6C9E65B42.jpg

**notice the backslashes before whitespaces**

I'm trying to get the image using this function:

```
-(UIImage *) getImageFromURL:(NSString *)fileURL {
    UIImage * result;

    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileURL]];
    result = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    return result; //result is always nil
}
```

Is the problem related to the backslashes?
Any help is very much appreciated!

Sincerely,

Zoli

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileURL]`?

Comment: why? URLWithString is exactly the function to use

Comment: Because it looks like you're using a local file URL, but if it doesn't contain `file://` in front of it, it needs to be converted using `fileURLWithPath`.

Comment: can you provide a code explaining how you'd do it?

Comment: It's exactly the same as what you've got there, just replace `URLWithString:` with `fileURLWithPath:`...

Comment: ah i tried that, but didn't work. i worked it out though, i'm posting the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to not store the uri in the database, only the image name. (But still store the image in the documents directory)
Then with the following function the image can be retrieved:

```
- (UIImage*)loadImageWithName:(NSString*) name
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                      [NSString stringWithString: name] ];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    return image;
}
```